# Proof Involving Determinant in Deriving Transformation of Lattice Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\boldsymbol{B} = \left(\boldsymbol{b}_{1},\boldsymbol{b}_{2},\dots,\boldsymbol{b}_{n}\right)$ be a list of linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. The lattice generated by $\boldsymbol{B}$ is the set
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}\left(\boldsymbol{B}\right) &= \left\{\boldsymbol{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{m} \vert \boldsymbol{y} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\boldsymbol{b}_{i} \textrm{ for some list of integers } \boldsymbol{x} = \left(x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{n}\right) \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}\right\}\\
&= \left\{\boldsymbol{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{m} \vert \boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{B} \boldsymbol{x},\ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}\right\}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The determinant of a lattice is defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
\det{\left(\mathcal{L}\left(\boldsymbol{B}\right)\right)} = \sqrt{\det{ \left({\boldsymbol{B}}^{\textrm{T}}\boldsymbol{B}\right) }}.
\end{equation}

I am trying to prove the following theorem: assume that $\boldsymbol{B} = \left(\boldsymbol{b}_{1}, \boldsymbol{b}_{2}, \dots, \boldsymbol{b}_{n}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Also assume that $\mathcal{A}: \mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is a linear transformation defined by a matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{A} \cdot \boldsymbol{x},\ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}.
\end{equation}
Assume that a new basis ${\boldsymbol{B}}^{\prime}$ is formed as follows:
\begin{equation}
{\boldsymbol{B}}^{\prime} = \boldsymbol{A} \cdot \boldsymbol{B}.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
\det{\mathcal{L}\left({\boldsymbol{B}}^{\prime}\right)} = \lvert{\det{\boldsymbol{A}}}\rvert\cdot\det{\mathcal{L}\left(\boldsymbol{B}\right)}.
\end{equation}

My proof goes as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\left(\det{ \mathcal{L}\left(\boldsymbol{B}^{\prime}\right) }\right)^{2} = \det{ \left({{\boldsymbol{B}}^{\prime}}^{\mathrm{T}} {\boldsymbol{B}}^{\prime}\right) } = \det{\left({\left(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{B}\right)}^{\mathrm{T}} \left(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{B}\right)\right)} = \det{\left({\boldsymbol{B}}^{\mathrm{T}}\left({\boldsymbol{A}}^{\mathrm{T}}\boldsymbol{A}\right)\boldsymbol{B}\right)}\\
&\stackrel{1}{=} \left(\det{A}\right)^{2}\det{\left({\boldsymbol{B}}^{\mathrm{T}}\boldsymbol{B}\right)} = \left(\det{\boldsymbol{A}}\right)^{2}\left(\det{\mathcal{L}\left({\boldsymbol{B}}\right)}\right)^{2},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
for which I still need to prove equality 1. Who can help me prove equality 1?

Comment: Do you have a source for your conjectured equality (1), a book or lecture notes?

Comment: @WillJagy No. I never saw such an equation. I read the answer, and verified with the book I was reading. In the book, $m = n$ is implied, while I generalized the condition in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

true if $n=m.$  If not, we must have $n<m$  because you are given an independent set of $n$ vectors in $R^m.$

We might as well try examples with $n=1.$  Take the matrix

$$
B= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2 \\
3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where we see that $B^T B$  is the 1 by 1 matrix with entry $13,$  which is also its determinant.

Then take

$$
A= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1&2 \\
3&11 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
of determinant $5$

Next
$$
B'=AB= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
8 \\
39 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and $B'^T B$ is the one by one matrix with entry $1585$

However,
$$  25 \cdot 13 \neq 1585  $$

Comment: I see. Thanks. I double checked the condition, and $n = m$ is required.